# linux logstash forwarder ssl IP SANS

Tags: openssl, docker, logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder

I am learning how to use logstash and logstash-forwarder.
The problem is logstash doesnt allow comms with SSL.
I am using IP method rather than DNS.
Kibana, Elastic Search and Logstash are installed inside a docker container.
I have generated a certificate within the container. Inside there, I have `/etc/pki/tls/{certs,private}` directories, holding the .crt and .key files respectively. I have copied those to the docker host.
If I run `openssl x509 -noout -text -in logstash-forwarder.crt` I can see inside the cert I have:

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            IP Address:172.17.0.47
```

Which is the IP of the docker container that is going to serve kibana. 
Inside the docker container that I am using as a test subject to send the logs (it is running a php app and nginx) I have the logstash.json config file that has:

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "172.17.0.47:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "/srv/logstash/logstash-forwarder.crt"
}
```

At the location `/srv/logstash/logstash-forwarder.crt` I can see that it is the same key and also has the lines:

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            IP Address:172.17.0.47
```

in it. I.e the SANS is 172.17.0.47
When I then run `./logstash-forwarder --config /srv/logstash/logstash.json` I get

> 2015/07/24 07:57:16.835391 Setting trusted CA from file:
>   /srv/logstash/logstash-forwarder.crt 2015/07/24 07:57:16.835949
>   Connecting to [172.17.0.47]:5000 (172.17.0.47) 2015/07/24
>   07:57:16.852710 Failed to tls handshake with 172.17.0.47 x509: cannot
>   validate certificate for 172.17.0.47 because it doesn't contain any IP
>   SANs 2015/07/24 07:57:17.856153 Connecting to [172.17.0.47]:5000
>   (172.17.0.47) 2015/07/24 07:57:17.874499 Failed to tls handshake with
>   172.17.0.47 x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.17.0.47 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

I'm very confused as I can see it in there myself. So what I am doing wrong?
Thanks